# Jquery Scroll to Anchor -60px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I have this JQuery function, and I would like it to scroll to possition - 60px, because I got a fixed navbar that is overlapping the content. How can I add this 60px to this code?

```
/**
 * Scroll to section
 * @param  string des HTML identity of section block
 * @return void
 */
function goToSectionID(des){
    var os = (history.pushState)?51:0;
    os = (jQuery(window).width()>800)?os:0;

    var pos = (jQuery(des).length>0 )?jQuery(des).offset().top-os:0;
    onanimate = true;
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:pos},1000,function(){
        if(history.pushState){
            history.pushState(null,null,des);
        }else   window.location.hash = des;
        jQuery(window).scrollTop(pos);
        onanimate=false
    });
}
```

Comment: `jQuery(window).scrollTop(pos - 60);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is overly complicated, or too simplistic, depends, but we have not seen your code.

Easiest way:

```
$(".arrowimg").click(function () {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#in').offset().top += 500
   },500);
  });
```

First line is obviously, eventListener and handler. Second line, target html and body for cross browser reasons. Use the animate method. ScrollTop, then the target with the ID anchor as in here in the HTML

```
<div class="arrowimg" id="in"></div>
```

Then I don't know if you want to go 60 px further up or down, as we haven't got your code but it's a matter of a + or -.

Here's the link

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/zBLEXR